# Python macros QGIS, change directory up

Tags: pyqgis

I wish to change the directory of a file up of one level in the QGIS Macros. I tried this code but I got the Error:

```
File "", line 10, in openProject
TypeError: cdUp(self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QDir'
```

my script :

```
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir

def openProject():

    from qgis.core import QgsProject
    old_root_folder = "/home/qgis/base/1_QGISData"
    proj_root = QgsProject.instance().homePath()
    proj_files_folder = "/1_QGIS_Projetdata/"
    new_root_folder = QDir.cdUp(proj_root) + proj_files_folder
    print(new_root_folder)

    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        name = layer.name()
        old_url = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
        new_url = old_url.replace(old_root_folder, new_root_folder)
        provider = layer.providerType()
        options = layer.dataProvider().ProviderOptions()
        layer.setDataSource(new_url, name, provider, options)

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

What do I do wrong?

PS: The proj_files_folder is in a totally different directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that QDir.cdUp(proj_root) will only return a **bool** not a string or path.  If you import os and use the split and join functions it may be easier.  Using os.path.dirname(*your_path_here*) will get the parent directory.  An example below.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir

def openProject():
    proj_root = QgsProject.instance().homePath()
    cur_path = QDir.currentPath()
    print(cur_path)
    print(proj_root)
    proj_files_folder = "/1_QGIS_Projetdata/"
    bool_change = QDir.cdUp(QDir(cur_path))
    print(bool_change)
    print(QDir.currentPath())
    
    parent = os.path.dirname(cur_path)
    print(parent)
    data_dir = os.path.join(parent, proj_files_folder)
    print(data_dir)

openProject()
```